# SQL query average over 100 days at a gap of 7 days

Tags: mysql, sql

So, for this query I need to use 2 columns which are date and value. I need to query the average of value over 100 days at a gap of 7 days, in layman terms I want the average value for all 7 days in a week over a time span of 100 days.

Value in my database depicts the revenue. For example, what I am trying to get is the average of revenue over last 100 wednesdays. Similarly for every 7 days in the week.

Answer (score 1):

If I am correct this is the query you are looking for:

```
SELECT WEEKDAY(RecordDate), AVG(revenue)
FROM Table
GROUP BY WEEKDAY(RecordDate)
WHERE RecordDate BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL -700 DAY) AND NOW()
```

Comment: MySQL does not implement DATEPART(). Use DAYOFWEEK() or WEEKDAY() instead. MySQL does not implement GETDATE(), use CURRENT_DATE instead. `AVG(*)` is synthactically incorrect.

Comment: My bad I misread the tag and thought it was for SQL server, my new answer should help you.